# grails gorm critieria builder count returns incorrect value?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-3.3

According to [the latest GORM documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/api/index.html), the count() method of CriteriaBuilder should return "The result count".

I find this not to be true when a projection is used in the CriteriaBuilder; then count() seems to return the total number of instances in the class.

For example, in my test application this code

```
def c = gtest01.TestA.createCriteria()
c.list {
    projections {
        groupProperty 'grouping'
        count()
    }
}.each { t ->
    println "t $t"
}
```

prints 8 lines, as expected:

```
t [1, 12]
t [2, 16]
t [3, 9]
t [4, 18]
t [5, 5]
t [6, 20]
t [7, 13]
t [8, 7]
```

whereas this code

```
c = gtest01.TestA.createCriteria()
c.count {
    projections {
        groupProperty 'grouping'
        count()
    }
}.each { t ->
    println "t $t"
}
```

prints

```
t 100
```

which is the total number of instances of TestA.

It seems to me either the documentation is wrong or the count() code is wrong.  I'd like the problem to be with the code, since I can always get the total number of instances of the class with a call to `gtest01.TestA.count()`

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284909/grails-3-3-gorm-where-query-with-projection-count-different-than-list-size which you opened a few days ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grails 3.3 gorm where query with projection count() different than list().size()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284909/grails-3-3-gorm-where-query-with-projection-count-different-than-list-size)

Comment: Daniel, no not a duplicate.  The other one is DetachedCriteria, this is Criteria.

Comment: Billjamesdev not a duplicate where query produces a DetachedCriteria, this is a Criteria builder.

Comment: I should add in relation to both comments above, the result yielded by count() is different - in the case of this issue, the value returned is the total number of instances in the class; in the other issue, one of the rows returned is picked up by the count(), which to me is a much more serious bug.  Someone could argue in this case that it is the documentation, not the behaviour of count(), that is incorrect.